# Ray to get ground point cannot get ground point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481916/in-unity-how-to-convert-event-current-mouseposition-to-screen-position)

I hope my script can make object follow my mouse move[image] like following

here is my script:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TestMouseDragObjectInSceneMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _cube;

    private GameObject cube
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_cube)
            {
                var c = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Obj/Cube");
                _cube = Instantiate(c);
            }

            return _cube;
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate += OnSceneGUI;
    }

    private void OnSceneGUI(SceneView sceneview)
    {
        var ev = Event.current;
        if (ev.type == EventType.MouseMove)
        {
            var ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(ev.mousePosition);
            var hit = new RaycastHit();
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
            {
                cube.transform.position = hit.point;
               Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(ev.mousePosition, hit.point));
            }
            else
            {
                var ptr = ray.GetPoint(100);
                cube.transform.position = ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate -= OnSceneGUI;
    }

    Vector3 GetMousePos(Event ev)
    {
        return GUIUtility.ScreenToGUIPoint(ev.mousePosition);
    }
}
```

above code will cause object suddenly become huge, if i the intersection point is ground point, the object size in scene view should stable, I think I doesn't get ground point but other intersection point, how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the reason caused your problem: your ray is casted on the cube itself some times.

to fix it, you got at least two options:

1) change the layer of your cube to 'ignoreRayCast', or pass a specified layer mask of the plane to the Physics.Raycast(...)

2) create a [Plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) to represent your 'ground', use the 'Raycast(...)' member method of it instead of Physics.Raycast(...)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Zhang Qi, I fix it with make sure object layer is "Ignore Raycast" like `cube.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast")`

following is my full code:

```
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;

    namespace Draft
    {
        [ExecuteInEditMode]
        public class TestMouseDragObjectInSceneMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
        {
            private GameObject _cube;

            private GameObject cube
            {
                get
                {
                    if (!_cube)
                    {
                        var c = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Obj/Cube");
                        _cube = Instantiate(c);
                    }

                    return _cube;
                }
            }

            private void OnEnable()
            {
                SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate += OnSceneGUI;
            }

            private void OnSceneGUI(SceneView sceneview)
            {
                var ev = Event.current;
                if (ev.type == EventType.MouseMove)
                {
                    cube.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
    //                Vector2 mousePos = Event.current.mousePosition;
    //                mousePos.y = sceneview.camera.pixelHeight - mousePos.y;
    //                var ray = sceneview.camera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
                    var ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(ev.mousePosition);
    //                cube.transform.position = ptr;
                    var hit = new RaycastHit();
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5))
                    {
                        cube.transform.position = hit.point;
    //                    Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(ev.mousePosition, hit.point));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var ptr = ray.GetPoint(5);
                        cube.transform.position = ptr;
                    }
                }
            }

            private void OnDisable()
            {
                SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate -= OnSceneGUI;
            }

            Vector3 GetMousePos(Event ev)
            {
                return GUIUtility.ScreenToGUIPoint(ev.mousePosition);
            }
        }

}
```